# How do I connect from a MVC3 .net application to a MySQL database through a SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, web-config, ssh-tunnel

I am building a .net MVC3 application using Entity Framework 4.  One of the databases I would like to connect with has to be accessed through a SSH tunnel.  Is there a way to do this through the web.config?  If not, what approaches should I consider?

Thanks,
Afrieze

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/